# How to execute macro associated with a check box in a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I am working on an analysis template with a UserForm.
I have macros associated with checkboxes. I want to activate them by clicking the separate analysis command box. The macros are called: graph_dur, graph_ram, dur_calc, ram_calc.

The UserForm allows users to check off the analyses they want, then run calculations with an "Analysis" command button.

[image]

Any boxes that are not checked should not run their macros when "Analyze" is clicked.

**I understand** that when a checkbox is "checked" then it returns "True".
**I don't know** how to associate the True return with the run of a macro when "Analyze" is activated.

This code is not correct, but attempts to highlight my basic layout.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click() 
    If CheckBox1 = True
        Then Call.Graph_duration
    Else CheckBox1 = False
    End If 
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    If CheckBox2 = True
        Then Call.Graph_ram
        Else CheckBox2 = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "seperate analysis command box"?

Comment: Try using CheckBox1.Value =True, however on the way you are making the code, you already call the functions, normally you would create a button that checks all the Checkboxes and then call the functions

Comment: Sorry, Bad wording on my part. In the picture attached, there is a command button called Analyze. It is this button that should be activated to run the macros associated with the checked off boxes.

Comment: Thats a good point dantakeshi, its gets to the root of my question. That is, how do you recognize which boxes have been selected by the user, then run only those "checked" macros. There are some macros that will go un-used because certain users might not need them for there analyses.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this - it should be attached to your button. If you had lots of checkboxes then this will become inefficient.

```
Private Button_Click()

    If CheckBox1 Then
        Graph_Duration
    End If

    If CheckBox2 Then
        Graph_ram
    End If
    'etc

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this saying: "If CheckBox 1 has been checked, do graph_..."?

Comment: If none of the boxed are checked would it just do nothing?

Comment: Yes. Note that Then is on the same line as If. You don't need to specify `=True` and your Else was redundant as far as I could see.

Comment: Aha. Many thanks SJR. I know what I need from my code, but have very little expertise with VBA syntax.

Comment: To save space you can write `If CheckBox1 Then Graph_Duration` on a single line and dispense with the `End If`. If it answers your question, perhaps you could accept it?

Comment: Yes I will accept. Just out of curiosity, what does that give to your profile?

Comment: I get 15 points I think, and you get some points but I don't know how many - presumably you should get a notification. I'm sure it's all explained somewhere.

Comment: After trying this solution I have found it does not work. When I press the analyze button in the userform none of the macros enabled by the checkbox work. I believe you must call them in the If statements after all

Comment: Are you saying it did work and stopped working, or it never worked (in which case why did you accept it as an answer?) In any case, I don't know what you mean by the macros don't work. More details needed.